# sending/receiving objects through tcpclient

Tags: c#, serialization, tcpclient

I have to send/recieve objects (of a custom class made by me) in my C# .NET 4.0 application and I would like a good tutorial to get me started because I've searched on Google and there seem to be a lot of problems with serialization/deserialization and although the problems were solved, there are a lot of ugly hacks.

Regards,
Alexandru Badescu

Comment: Are you communicating with an unmanaged app or are both endpoints managed and controlled by you? If the latter is the case, you might want to consider WCF (possibly with TCP/IP binding)

Comment: NB: it is customary on SO to leave out 'hello' and 'regards'. Just ask the question :)

Comment: @ohadsc both endpoints are managed by me @tykhyy i leave them out in the future :D

Comment: Then consider WCF - should make life easier for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a transport that does just this:

http://fadd.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/58859#1054822

The library is work in progress, but the BinaryTransport works. It will also attempt to reconnect if it get disconnected.

**Example:**

```
public class Example
{
    private BinaryTransport<Packet> _client;
    private ServerExample _server;

    public void Run()
    {
        // start server
        _server = new ServerExample();
        _server.Start(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1234));

        // start client
        _client = new BinaryTransport<Packet>(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1234));

        // send stuff from client to server
        _client.Send("Hello world!");

        // send custom object
        _client.Send(new User { FirstName = "Jonas", LastName = "Gauffin" });
    }
}


public class ServerExample
{
    private readonly List<BinaryTransport<Packet>> _clients = new List<BinaryTransport<Packet>>();
    private SimpleServer _server;

    private void OnClientAccepted(Socket socket)
    {
        var client = new BinaryTransport<Packet>(socket);
        client.Disconnected += OnDisconnected;
        client.ObjectReceived += OnObject;

        _clients.Add(client);
    }

    private void OnDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var transport = (BinaryTransport<Packet>) sender;
        transport.Disconnected -= OnDisconnected;
        transport.ObjectReceived -= OnObject;
    }

    private void OnObject(object sender, ObjectEventArgs<Packet> e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We received: " + e.Object.Value);
    }

    public void Start(IPEndPoint listenAddress)
    {
        _server = new SimpleServer(listenAddress, OnClientAccepted);
        _server.Start(5);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Packet
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**

I've made a new framework: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-networking-a-somewhat-performant-networking-library-for-net/

Comment: I saw that, thanks =) The BinaryTransport is another class in the library though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the objects you could decorate them with the [`[Serializable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute and use [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) for serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

For TCP/IP communication I highly recommend [Stephen Cleary's FAQ](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html), you should pay special attention to [Message Framing](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html). You might also want to take a look at his [NitoSockets](http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/) implementation.

All that assuming you can't just use WCF, of course.